# Вопрос по построению бизнес-процесса

Tags: битрикс24

Нужно построить бизнес-процесс с 2 действиями: 1 - при переходе в определенную стадию, сделка копируется в другой канбан, 2 - исходная сделка ждет перехода скопированной сделки в определенную стадию и сама переходит после этого в другую стадию. С копированием всё понятно, нужна помощь на 2 этапе

Answer (score 0):

Сделай в копии сделке техническое поле с ID родительской сделки. При переходе копии в нужную стадию запускай отдельный БП чтобы перенести родителя в нужную стадию.

Comment: вы же как-то нашли этот вопрос, правильно? а чтобы его нашли и другие, неплохо было бы дать вопросу более подходящий заголовок (да и текст). и движок сайта даже поощряет такие действия со стороны отвечающего: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/refiner), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/illuminator).